# Intall BURG in fakeRAID UEFI system

Tags: 12.10, grub2, dual-boot, uefi, burg

I am currently dual booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 in UEFI mode, on a system with a fake(motherboard) RAID 0 configuration. I first installed Windows 8, then Ubuntu 12.10 and used **BootRepair** to set up GRUB2 configuration automatically. Everything is working, however I want to install **BURG**, and I do not know where to install it with **burg-install**. It seems that GRUB2 is using windows EFI partition to mount `/boot/efi`:

```
joao@desktop-qq:~$ lsblk
NAME                            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
sda                               8:0    0  76.7G  0 disk   
└─isw_eaidfhhhaa_raid (dm-0)    252:0    0 153.4G  0 dmraid 
  ├─isw_eaidfhhhaa_raid1 (dm-1) 252:1    0   300M  0 part   
  ├─isw_eaidfhhhaa_raid2 (dm-2) 252:2    0    99M  0 part   /boot/efi
  ├─isw_eaidfhhhaa_raid3 (dm-3) 252:3    0   128M  0 part   
  ├─isw_eaidfhhhaa_raid4 (dm-4) 252:4    0  99.5G  0 part   /media/joao/BEBE305B
  └─isw_eaidfhhhaa_raid5 (dm-5) 252:5    0  53.4G  0 part   /
sdb                               8:16   0  76.7G  0 disk   
└─isw_eaidfhhhaa_raid (dm-0)    252:0    0 153.4G  0 dmraid 
  ├─isw_eaidfhhhaa_raid1 (dm-1) 252:1    0   300M  0 part   
  ├─isw_eaidfhhhaa_raid2 (dm-2) 252:2    0    99M  0 part   /boot/efi
  ├─isw_eaidfhhhaa_raid3 (dm-3) 252:3    0   128M  0 part   
  ├─isw_eaidfhhhaa_raid4 (dm-4) 252:4    0  99.5G  0 part   /media/joao/BEBE305B
  └─isw_eaidfhhhaa_raid5 (dm-5) 252:5    0  53.4G  0 part   /
```

So where exactly should I point **burg-install**?
On the other hand, my goal is just to have a graphical interface to the bootloader, and I was wondering if that's possible with any of the GRUB2 EFI alternatives (ELILO, rEFInd, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BURG is old ([2010](http://code.google.com/p/burg/downloads/list)), so it won't work with UEFI.
You probably want to try ReFind.